# adjusting an array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

given an array of numbers, what's a good way to adjust one number and amortize the difference proportionally over *certain* of the other items in the array?

given:

> var array = [10,20,30,40,50]

-> adjust the third item up by 30 and subtract **proportionally** across the first and last such that the sum of the items still totals 150 (second and fourth elements in the array are fixed or should remain the same).

= should come out to : [5,20,60,40,25]

(ideally javascript, but I could translate from C# / VB.net if that's preferable)

Comment: If you want proportional adjustments, are you ok with elements 0 and 4 being non-integer? And is element 2 the only one that can be adjusted by the user?

Comment: in this particular case, that's it. I'm trying to adjust column widths while keeping the table width the same. Some of the cells are "fixed" or should not be adjusted (columns 0 and 4 in my example)

Comment: HTML table column widths, or some other column widths?

Comment: HTML table column widths

Comment: well, it's more like my knapsack problem  -everything's gotta fit in there!! ;)

Comment: @Joshua: You would do better to let the browser do this for by constraining your HTML table width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general purpose JS function to split the adjustment evenly across all the other items in the array:

```
var array = [10,20,30,40,50];

function amortize(list, index, amount) {
    if (list.length <= 1) return;    // can't amortize with 0 or 1 items in list
    var remaining = amount / (list.length - 1);
    list[index] += amount;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (i != index) {
            list[i] -= remaining;
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want a non-general function that just adjusts the ends and leaves the ones on either side of the middle untouched, then you would just do this:

```
var array = [10,20,30,40,50];

function amortizeEnds(list, amount) {
    var remaining = amount / 2;
    list[0] -= remaining;
    list[4] -= remaining;
    list[2] += amount;
}
```

I'm not sure I understand your **proportional** request, but here's one that gives you the result you asked for:

```
var array = [10,20,30,40,50];

function amortizeEndsProportional(list, amount) {
    var endsTotal = list[0] + list[4];
    var reductionProportion = amount / endsTotal;
    list[0] = list[0] - list[0] * reductionProportion;
    list[4] -= list[4] - list[4] * reductionProportion;
    list[2] += amount;
}
```

You can see the last one work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/QayQp/.

Comment: You'll likely need to make the values for indices 0 and 4 integers, since he's using them as column widths. Of course, if we're talking HTML table column widths, there's a much better way to do all of this.

Comment: @Jonathan M - the whole request is under-specified so I stayed as general as possible.  He can add more detail to his liking.  Lots of boundary conditions weren't specified like if the amount of adjustment is too large for the smaller end bucket and it goes to zero?  What if an odd value is passed that can't be split evenly?  What if one column rounds down to zero and can never be adjusted up again?  Lots of boundary conditions not specified.  Because of that last condition, the array itself should probably contain the decimal values and do rounding to integer upon conversion to the actual UI.

Comment: It sure does get tricky, real fast. Thanks for the help with this answer! I'll work out the details on that.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the following snippet could help:

```
function amortize(array, updatedValueIndex, delta, amortizeIndexes){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < amortizeIndexes.length; i++){
        sum += array[amortizeIndexes[i]];
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < amortizeIndexes.length; i++){
        array[amortizeIndexes[i]] -= delta * array[amortizeIndexes[i]] / sum;
        if (array[amortizeIndexes[i]] < 0) array[amortizeIndexes[i]] = 0;
    }

    array[updatedValueIndex] += (delta > sum) ? sum : delta;        

    return array;
}

amortize([10,20,30,40,50], 2, 30, [0, 4]);
```

Comment: It was really difficult to award acceptance to either yourself or jfriend00, because both helped me get there more simply than how I'd tried to go about it. Thanks for the response. +1